# Get field values from user set values for hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post

I have a hidden field value in html.
User can only see username/password and set those values, but when user sets username value, how do I change the value in the hidden field?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Let's say user entered in user1/pass1 for username/password in the login page.
I have the hidden field below. I want this field to be submitted as name=user1. If user sets user2/pass2, I want this field below to be submitted as name=user2. How do I do this?

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="arg" placeholder="name=username">
```

Instead of replacing the whole username, it has to be like this.
If user sets stack, it has to be 'name='stack'

```
username=stack
password=userset
arg='name=stack'
```

Below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Please Log In</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="http" method="POST" form id="form1">


            <div class="login">
                <div class="login-screen">
                    <div class="app-title">
                        <h1> Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="arg" placeholder="name=username" id="hiddenUsername">
                                <p><input type="submit" value="Log In" /></p>
        </form>



        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                              $('form#form1').submit(function(){
                                                     $.ajax({type: "Post",
                                                            url: $('form').attr('action'),
                                                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                                                            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                                                            alert("Login successful. ");
                                                            window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "http/"},5000);},
                                                            error: function(data, status, xhr) {
                                                            $('form').trigger("reset");
                                                            alert("Failed to login.");
                                                            }
                                                            });

                                                     return false;
                                                     alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
                                                     });

$('#username').keyup(function() {
    $('#hiddenUsername').val("name%3d" + $('#username').val());
});
                              });

            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using pure JavaScript:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="arg" placeholder="name=username" id="hiddenUsername">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = document.getElementById("username");
    var hidden = document.getElementById("hiddenUsername");
    username.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        hidden.value = "name%3d" + username.value;
    });
</script>
```

If you are already using [jQuery](https://jquery.com) elsewhere and would like to use it, here is the jQuery version (although the pure JavaScript version will be more efficient):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="arg" placeholder="name=username" id="hiddenUsername">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#username').keyup(function() {
        $('#hiddenUsername').val("name%3d" + $('#username').val());
    });
</script>
```

Notice my addition of the `id` attributes in your first and third `input` tags. The `id` attribute allows the JavaScript to identify a unique element of the DOM (or [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)) so that we can interact with it.

This code binds the `keyup` event listener to the username field. This will effectively mirror the username field and the hidden username field, and update every time a key is released inside the username input field.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the post to reflect what I need. Instead of replacing the whole username, it has to be like this. Can you see if you could revise it in the jquery?
If user sets stack, it has to be 'name='stack'

    username=stack
    password=userset
    arg='name=stack'

Comment: @user17651, I understand. I've edited my answer. Please let me know if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't seem to work. Can you see my code and possibly add in what's missing? I am trying to do a post call and it needs  something like this. username=stack
password=userset
arg='name=stack'

Comment: I think the problem might be that the `=` wasn't being encoded, and was confusing the browser. I've corrected that by URL encoding the `=` sign. Please let me know if this works. If not, please provide some output to help me debug it.

Comment: Can you see my code to debug what could be wrong? It doesn't seem to work. So if it was a text field, and user had to enter it, he would  put in 'name=stack'.

Comment: Here is a link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08beh6mb/ It's definitely working. The '=' is being encoded to '%3d' so the URL accepts it. I'm not sure what isn't working on the server side, though.

Comment: All I changed in that Fiddle is that the hidden input is no longer hidden. Everything else is the pure JavaScript version I provided.